# How to scatter Greebles on target object with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, scatter-objects-addon

Hello Blender Community!

I'm still quite a geometry noob.
I'm wondering if it's possible to scatter greebles from a collection onto a target object such as a spaceship or building and that the greebles can be brought to the edge of the target object, i.e. not overlapping. It would be also great if they bending around the edge.

Some time ago I saw a 3ds max addon that does exactly that and I wonder if it's also possible in blender: [http://www.automodeller.com](http://www.automodeller.com/)

I tried it here in my screenshots, but the greebles go over the edges of the target object on which they are to be scattered (see screenshots). Does anyone of you have an idea how to use the method in the 3Ds max addon in Blender? This would be soooo great. Thank you in advance!

enter image description here
[image]
[image]

[image: Greeble Test like the with the AutoModeller Pro Addon]f-code-artists

Comment: Possibly useful suggestion. Please see [remesh modifier] to reduce the face size and the error.  This does not address the problem of trying to fill triangles with rectangular tiles.  If you use [vertex groups] you might avoid the edges.  For distance shots this may be adequate ... you can be the judge.  For close up shots you can be the judge.

Comment: Possibly useful suggestion.  If [remesh modifier] and vertex groups are used.  A different tile might be used for the edges.  I hope someone else will mention an add-on for you.